# Read information from inside DEB package in preinst

Tags: ubuntu, debian, deb

I am creating DEB package for Ubuntu which copies binary and configuration files. When I am installing/reinstalling with a new DEB file in case of patch, upgrade or downgrade, I need information in preinst file.
I need to know the version of binary shipped with my package, and compare it with one already installed, and perform action accordingly. Binary version can be found using `./binary --version`

Is there a way to get the file packaged inside DEB and run commands on it as part of preinst script. I am also ok, if I can hardcode this information in control file, and read control file in preinst script.

Comment: On your preinst script you already have the information about the previous version. Or I miss something?

Comment: https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html section 6.6  the point 3: you get the version of old package. But please be careful on what you are doing: packages are done to simplifying your living, not to make too much logic (and so being a black box which may fails unexpectedly: do not assume you will code all cases, and you will handle only your packed packages)

Comment: This is my first attempt for DEB. My package needs user inputs in order to work. And I need to perform investigation steps before upgrade/patch. I thought preinst postinst prerm postrm scripts would work. I saw upgrade process at https://wiki.debian.org/MaintainerScripts to be complicated with lot of flows to be catered. Is there a better way to handle this? Any example repository which handles configurations upgrade and removals will be helpful too.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi keeping previous version information, and coding the current version info in script, makes it very specific to the version I am building. Reading from DEB ensures I keep the script as it is, update binary and publish it. I am trying to figure out what is ideal way of building packages.